# Passing Futures as arguments in Dask

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

What is the best way to pass a `Future` to a Dask Delayed function such that the `Future` stays in tact? In other words, how can we ensure the function will get the actual `Future` and not the result it represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the semantics are that dask.delayed functions get concrete results rather than dask-y ones.  This is not easily supported today without some tricks.

That being said, I recommend the following trick:

#### Place your future in a [Variable](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Variable)

```
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, Variable
client = Client()

v = Variable()

@dask.delayed
def f(v):
    return v.get().result()

future = client.scatter(123)
f(future).compute()
# 123
```

Comment: Thanks. That does seem reasonable.

Also found that `dask.core.literal` worked, would that be a reasonable thing to use?

Comment: Hrm, yes, that seems like a better idea.  I recommend raising a PR to push that into the top-level API and pinging jcrist to see what his thoughts are.